# Unity CS0308 error: The non-generic method cannot be used with the type arguments

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, google-vr

I have trying to build a game in Unity3D and I am using Unity 5.1.1 pro version, I have imported Google VR sdk, and I am getting this error.

```
void Awake() {
#if !UNITY_5_2
         // im getting a error on this line 
        GetComponentInChildren<VideoControlsManager>(true).Player = player;
#else
    GetComponentInChildren<VideoControlsManager>().Player = player;
#endif
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the signatures of GetComponentInChildren in 5.1.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Component.GetComponentsInChildren` because it takes a boolean value to include the inactive objects, but because it returns an array you can use an `ForEach` to assign your variable to each element

```
 public VideoControlsManager[] VideoControlsManagers;
VideoControlsManagers = GetComponentsInChildren<VideoControlsManager>(true);

        foreach( VideoControlsManager v in VideoControlsManagers )
            v.Player  = player;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html)'s first line, there isn't a `<generictype>` acceptable. But the example uses the `<generictype>`. You might submit a ticket to see which is correct. Because of the error, I suspect the definition line is the correct way of writing it. So...

Write your line this way:

```
GetComponentInChildren(typeof(VideoControlsManager)).Player = player;
```